# When to use Monte Carlo over TD learning, and vice-versa

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, montecarlo, temporal-difference

When studying Reinforcement learning, and exactly when it comes to Model-Free RL, there are two methods we use generally:

- TD learning
- Monte Carlo

When is each one of them used over the other? In other words, how do we figure out what method is best for our problem?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22723830/when-to-use-a-certain-reinforcement-learning-algorithm

Answer (score 2):

Sections 6.1 and 6.2 of [Sutton & Barto](http://incompleteideas.net/book/the-book-2nd.html) give a very nice intuitive understanding of the difference between Monte Carlo and TD learning.

Having said that, there's of course the obvious incompatibility of MC methods with non-episodic tasks. In that case, you will always need some kind of bootstrapping.